# Paste variable names inside mutate(across())

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to set variable values that are NA in several columns to the values in different but similarly-named columns. I was wondering if this is possible using dplyr.

As an example, suppose I have the following data frame:

```
x <- tribble(~x_var1, ~x_var2, ~y_var1, ~y_var2,
             5, 2, 0, 0,
             NA, 10, 8, 0,
             3, NA, 0, 5,
             NA, NA, 7, 9)
```

and I want to replace `NA` values in `x_var1` and `x_var2` with the corresponding values in `y_var1` and `y_var2`. My dataset has more than two such columns so I was wondering whether there is a neat way to do this with `mutate(across(...))` or other dplyr operations.

My attempt is to do as follows:

```
x %>% 
  mutate(across(c(x_var1, x_var2),
         ~ ifelse(is.na(.), paste0("y_", str_remove(., "x_")), .))) # if NA replace with y_(varname)
```

But of course this doesn't work because the `paste` and `str_remove` functions are not operating on the variable name.

Thanks in advance!

(Edit: I suppose I could use `pivot_longer` / `pivot_wider` but I'm curious whether there are alternative solutions.)

Comment: I found the following thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61903103/dplyr-access-column-name-in-mutate-at-function which led to me this workaround - 

x %>% 
  mutate(across(c(x_var1, x_var2),
                ~ifelse(is.na(.), pull(x, paste("y_", str_remove(cur_column(), "x_"), sep = "")), .)))

Happy to hear other suggestions though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the approach you posted in your comment is ok. We could simplify it a bit:

```r
library(dplyr)

x <- tribble(~x_var1, ~x_var2, ~y_var1, ~y_var2,
             5, 2, 0, 0,
             NA, 10, 8, 0,
             3, NA, 0, 5,
             NA, NA, 7, 9)   

x %>%
  mutate(across(c(x_var1, x_var2),
                ~ ifelse(is.na(.),
                         get(gsub("^x_", "y_", cur_column())),
                         .))) 
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   x_var1 x_var2 y_var1 y_var2
#>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1      5      2      0      0
#> 2      8     10      8      0
#> 3      3      5      0      5
#> 4      7      9      7      9
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Another approach in the larger tidyverse would be to use `purrr::reduce` in combination with a custom function.

```r
my_replace_na <- function(df, x) {
  mutate(df, !! x := ifelse(is.na(!!sym(x)),
                            !!sym(gsub("^x_", "y_", x)),
                            !!sym(x)))
}

x %>% 
  purrr::reduce(c("x_var1", "x_var2"), my_replace_na, .init = .)
```

Comment: @AnilGoyal: Thanks! I meanwhile have [package](https://github.com/TimTeaFan/dplyover) on Github which solves similar problems.

Comment: Oh yes, I have noticed its mention in your other answers.